# Excel: How to convert number into number of digits. (111 -> 3)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to make an awesome excel document with the new excel.

I'm fairly new to the process but love the functions and find it relatively to use.

However, I'm trying to find an essay way to convert any number (e.g, 555555, 1111111) into the number of digits that are in that number (e.g., 555555 -> 6 or 11 -> 2 or 1111111111 -> 10).

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of digits using the LEN() function

E.G. LEN(555555) = 6 AND  LEN(11) = 2 AND LEN(1111111111) = 10

If you are referencing a cell E.G. cell A1 , then LEN(A1) will return the result as above depending on the value in the cell.